# How to chain lodash function calls properly

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I need to sort an array of objects, and then take the first item from it. How to achieve this in lodash?

```
_.sortBy(window.locations, [{ 'is_primary': 'desc' }])
```

this gives me a proper sorted array. how do I take the first element from it, using `_.first()` function? possibly chain them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_.chain` and then unwrap value:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chain

Another way would be just to wrap your result in `_.first` as lodash is protected from `undefined`, empty arrays, `null` and so on (the worst that can happen would be returning empty array):

```
_.first(_.sortBy(window.locations, [{ 'is_primary': 'desc' }]));
```

Side note about `_.chain` in the browser environment - it may cause your bundle to grow significantly (as it may incorporate a lot of `lodash` functions into your bundle), read this article if you're worried about that:

https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba

**TL;DR** If you're performing simple operation and care about your output JS bundle size, stick to just wrapping in `_.first` :)

Comment: `stick to just wrapping in _.first` even easier to read if you use `_.flow` to compose the functions together. Using Lodash/FP `_.flow(_.first, _.sortBy([{ 'is_primary': 'desc' }])` will give you the function to then just call with your data.

Comment: Great. Working for me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First lets note that [**_.first is a alias of _.head**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#head) just so you know and do not get confused why they both do the same thing.

Also there is a difference to note between `_.sortBy` and `_.orderBy` which always comes up and should also be noted:

[**_.sortBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortBy) would allow you to sort by lodash `short` notation or via a function but **only in ascending order**!

[**_.orderBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) does the same but allows you to specify multiple fields **with also their sort order (asc/desc)**.

Consider these examples:

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 1, 'drinks': 1 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 4, 'drinks': 3 },
  { 'user': 'brat',   'age': 4, 'drinks': 6 },
  { 'user': 'josh',   'age': 2, 'drinks': 2 },
  { 'user': 'jim',    'age': 2, 'drinks': 10 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 3, 'drinks': 5}
];

const sortBy = _.sortBy(users, ['age','drinks'])
const orderBy = _.orderBy(users, ['age', 'drinks'], ['asc', 'desc'])

console.log('sortBy', sortBy)
console.log('orderBy', orderBy)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see from the output (when the users have the same age) when it comes to sorting multiple fields advantage goes to `orderBy` due to its convenience.

So back to your question:

You could use any of these:

```
// ONLY ASC
_.head(_.sortBy(window.locations, ['is_primary']));
_.first(_.sortBy(window.locations, ['is_primary']));

// ASC & DESC
_.head(_.orderBy(window.locations, ['is_primary'], ['desc']));
_.first(_.orderBy(window.locations, ['is_primary'], ['desc']));
```

And last [chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chain) overall is for convenience and readability mainly. IF you have more than 2 operations it gets tricky to read so the rule usually is if more than 2 then chain but if equal or less than that don't.

Most of the examples where chaining is used it is applied on more than 2 operations.

Also as pointed out just for chaining you need extra code from lodash which you might not want.